# How to get rid of the lace of transparent background colour on the html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, winforms

[image]

I have a WinForm,

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
```

In this WinForm, it has a web browser which shows a website.

In the Website:

```
body {
            background-color: magenta;
            margin: 0px;
        }
```

As you can see that the boundary of the picture has been filled up with the magenta colour, which isn't the colour from the picture itself. And it makes the UI look ugly.

My question is: how to get rid of the unexpected magenta lace around my backgroud picture.

**PS:
You can use Ctrl + rotate Mouse wheel upwards to enlarge the picture so that you can see the magenta lace clearer.**

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest changing the background-color of the body, but somehow I have the idea that would be too easy...

Comment: @MrLister hi, thx for replying. The reason why I have to set the body color as magenta is because it has to be the same color as the TransparencyKey. Otherwise you will see the color of body cover the whole screen.